# pivotX and PivotY on ScaleAnimation has no effect

Tags: android, graphics, view, tween, android-animation

I'm trying to scale a View equivalent to the right and left from center of a View using ScaleAnimation . Whatever values I set for pivotX and PivotY it always scale in the same way (like right edge appears to be scaling keeping left edge constant). Below is the code I used to initialize the ScaleAnimation. Can anyone please let me know, if Im doing anything wrong?. Thanks.

```
final ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialing the anim solved the problem.

I just used the below to code to initialise it.

```
    anim.initialize(/* animate view */child.getWidth(), 
                                     child.getHeight(),
                    /* parents view */ this.getWidth(), 
                                      this.getHeight());
```